# Spring MongoDB query regex

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I'm trying to query MongoDB using spring but I can't get my regex to work.

I have a tree in mongodb as Materialized Paths as in MongoDB docs (http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Trees+in+MongoDB).

In the shell the query

```
db.categories.find({path:/^\w+,$/})
```

works fine to find the path before the first comma.

Ex.: {"path" : "a,"} gets returned but not {"path: "a,b,"} which is what I want.

How do I make the same query in spring?
I've tried:

```
new Query(Criteria.where("path").regex("/^\\w+,$/"))
```

but this doesn't work.

Thank you

Comment: I don't know this Spring-MongoDB stuff. However, I know that you need to double-escape back-slashes in Java regexes. Also, you don't need the starting and ending slashes either: .regex("^\\\\w+,$") should work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just solved my problem.

```
query = new Query(Criteria.where("path").regex("^([A-Z]|[a-z])+,$"));
```

although **\w** stands for "any word character" which usually means alphanumeric, I just need the alphabet characters.

I can later throw **[0-9]** and **\_** to have the same as **\w**.

If someone can explain how to make **\w** to work, I'll be very thankful :)

Comment: in you first example you've used `/` int he begining an end, whereas in the second you didn't use `/` character.

Comment: Like 'tamas rev' said on the question comment, there is no need to use those slashes